# Event when list of uploads has changed

Tags: angularjs, fine-uploader

I'm integrating Fine Uploader into an existing workflow. The user needs to provide a bit of metadata and select a file, then click Upload.

The Upload button should be disabled until a file is selected. If the user deletes the file, it should go back to disabled. I have `autoUpload:false`.

I'm using AngularJS so I'm binding to a function which invokes `$("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderS3('getUploads')`, and seems like a nice way to handle it.

However, I need a way to get notified when the list has changed, so I can trigger the digest cycle and update the UI. I've tried registering callbacks for the `submitted` and `cancel` events, which works – except that cancel is called when the upload is still in the list.

Is there a cleaner way to get a callback when the user adds or removes a file from the list of uploads?

Comment: Are you using Fine Uploader UI, or Fine Uploader Basic/Core with your own complete UI?  I'm guessing the latter (no UI elements provided by Fine Uploader) but want to confirm.

Comment: Hi! I'm using Fine Uploader UI, I think. `s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.1.1.js`, `$("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderS3()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, listening for the "cancel" event is not appropriate.  Why?  Because the file/upload is not actually cancelled when your cancel callback is invoked due to the fact that you are able to abort the cancel attempt via your callback handler's return value.

You can be sure that the file has been cancelled internally by listening for the [`statusChange` event](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#statuschange).  When it has truly been cancelled, your `statusChange` event handler will be called with the file ID and a newStatus parameter of `qq.status.CANCELED`.

You can read more on [status change handling in the docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/statistics-and-status-updates.html).

UPDATE: Since you are using Fine Uploader UI, the file is not removed from the UI until just after this status is updated.  This doesn't seem like an issue for you though, since you are utilizing the `getUploads` method to determine file status.

Comment: Thanks for correcting that spelling mistake (CANCELED vs CANCELLED).  Looks like the docs have the same typo.

Comment: Yeah! With JavaScript that's tough, I didn't even notice it wasn't working. Maybe you can set them both on `qq.status`?

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but the proper status value has always been qq.status.CANCELED.  I'm pushing an update now that ensures a consistent spelling of this word across the code and docs.

Comment: Okay. By the way, thanks for the super-fast response!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working solution, in case it's useful to someone else:

```
$scope.uploader = $('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3({
    ...
}).on('statusChange', function (event, id, oldStatus, newStatus) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.$digest();
    });
});

$scope.has_selected_file = function () {
    if (!$scope.uploader) return false;
    var uploads = $scope.uploader.fineUploaderS3('getUploads');
    var result = _(uploads).some(function (item) {
        return item.status !== qq.status.CANCELED;
    });
    return result;
};
```

(Uses [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/))